# Why is "ho theos" translated as "O God" in Hebrews 1:8 when "ho" is translated as "the" throughout the New Testament? Are there better translations?

Tags: translation-philosophy, hebrews

'o  qronoV  sou '**o**  qeoV    eiV ton aiwna   tou aiwnoV

ho  thronos sou **ho**  theos   eis ton aiona   tou ainos

the throne  of you  **the** God to  the age of the  age

The same **ho theos** is in Hebrews 1:9 but is translated **the God**. What is the reason for the inconsistency in translation?

O
ὁ (ho)
Article - Vocative Masculine Singular
Strong's 3588: **The**, the definite article. Including the feminine he, and the neuter to in all their inflections; the definite article; the.

Such translation makes Hebrews 1:9 like God's God anointing God to be above his partners.

The UBS Committee’s own comments says, Hebrews 1:8 “must be” translated “God is thy throne” and not “thy throne, O God.” - (study pp. 662-663 in A Textual Commentary on the Greek New Testament, United Bible Societies, 1971.)

Hebrews 1:8 NASB 1995

But of the Son He says, “YOUR THRONE, O GOD, IS FOREVER AND EVER, AND THE RIGHTEOUS SCEPTER IS THE SCEPTER OF HIS KINGDOM.

Who is this **"HIS"** if the Father is speaking to the son?

Comment: I can't find your citation in my copy (3rd corrected version from 1975). You seem be to conflating their various comments on the reading αὐτοῦ or σου. Actually they say the opposite of what you say they do. They say "Thus, if one reads αὐτοῦ (my note: which they do not) the words ὁ θεός must be taken, not as a vocative (an interpretation preferred by most exegetes), but as the subject (or predicate nominative), an interpretation that is regarded as highly improbable." So they are NOT saying what you write, but the opposite, since they read σου, not αὐτοῦ.

Comment: This has been dealt with, time and time again, in history and here. The outcome is indisputable, as answers here demonstrate.

Comment: @Nigel. The link that you suggested does not ask my first question, Why the Greek word "ho" was translated "O" when it's translated "the" in the New Testament.

Comment: The grammar of the sentence is a very simple construction. The same question can be looked at from a variety of aspects. It remains the same question.

Answer (score 5):

The Greek of the first part of Heb 1:8 says this:

> πρὸς δὲ τὸν Υἱόν Ὁ θρόνος σου ὁ **Θεὸς** ... = but to the Son [He
> declares], "Your throne O God ...

Daniel Wallace in "Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics" has this to say about this verse (page 59):

> There are three syntactical possibilities for Θεὸς here:
>
> - as subject ("God is your throne"), eg, Wescott, Moffatt, RSV margin, NRSV margin, NEB margin
> - predicate nominative ("your throne is God") - an excellent study of Heb 1:8, Harris could only find Hort and Nairne among the commentators
>   to hold this view (...)
> - nominative for vocative (as the translation above)
>
> The S and PN translations can be lumped together [see original for
> more details] and set off against the nominative for vocative
> approach.  It is our view that the nominative for vocative is to be
> preferred for the following reasons:
>
> 1. It is an overstatement to argue that if a writer wanted to address God he could have used the vocative Θεέ, because nowhere in the NT is
>    this done except in Matt 27:46.  The articular nom. for voc. is the
>    almost universal choice
> 2. This is especially the case in quoting from the LXX (as in Heb 1:8, cf Heb 10:7) for the LXX is equally reticent to use the voc.form, most
>    likely since Hebrew lacked such a form
> 3. The accentuation in the Hebrew is Ps 45:7 suggests that there should be a pause between "throne" and "God" (indicating that
>    tradition took "God" as direct address) [see footnote in original]
> 4. This view takes seriously the μὲν ... δὲ construction i vv 7-8, while the S-PN view does not adequately handle these conjunctions.
>    Specifically, if we read v 8 as "your throne is God" [see footnote of
>    original] then δὲ looses its adversarial force, for such a statement
>    could also be made of the angels, viz, that God reigns over the
>    angels. [see footnote in original].

Thus, in agreement with the above cogent arguments, ὁ Θεὸς is a nominative for vocative construction consistent with the rest of the NT and LXX and thus the translation of almost all modern translations is correct, "**

> ***your throne, O God ...***

**NOTE:**  See Wallace, GGBB for many other examples of Nominative for vocative.  Thus, it is NOT true that "ho" is translated "the" throughout the NT.  Indeed, it is translated in various ways such as:

- "the one", is as a pronoun
- vocative case - see Wallace GGBB for many details, page 56-59 and the dozens of examples cited
- sometimes it is left untranslated
- sometimes it is translated "the"
- etc.

The Greek article is thus not a direct equivalent of the English definite article.

Comment: +1 referenced well